# Broken upgrade of debian, causing perl issues

Tags: debian, apt, perl, aptitude, bugzilla

So I stuffed an upgrade of debian, both upgrade and dist-upgrade. I am more used to yum but thats no excuse.

Now things are being silly. The majority of things work, however, my bugzilla install fails. On loading bugzilla I get a 500 error and this is logged in the error.log;

```
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] Can't locate Email/Address.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 48.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 48.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Token.pm line 35.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Token.pm line 35.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Auth/Persist/Cookie.pm line 37.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Auth/Persist/Cookie.pm line 37.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 37.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 37.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla.pm line 31.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla.pm line 31.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] Compilation failed in require at /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34.
[Fri Jun 05 12:34:16 2009] [error] [client 172.20.0.160] Premature end of script headers: index.cgi
```

Also, when I run checksetup.pl from Bugzilla, it seems to end prematurely;

```
Checking user setup ...
Removing existing compiled templates ...
Precompiling templates ...
Not a subroutine reference at /usr/share/perl5/Bugzilla/Template.pm line 59.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/bugzilla/lib/checksetup.pl line 1291
```

I have reinstalled both perl and perl-base;

```
apt-get install --reinstall perl-base
apt-get install --reinstall perl
```

And have had no success.

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Also, this site is becoming a lifesaver for a systems-noob like myself and I am really thankful to all the help I get.

Christian

Comment: Hi.

Did you try to run apt-get -f install, It may fix your broken packages.

Answer (score 7):

I see that you already solved this with the CPAN shell, but it would be better to install with Debian packages, that way you have only one place to check for upgrades, etc...  In fact, I'll bet if you'd used the debian bugzilla package in the first place you wouldn't have run into this problem in the first place.

```
apt-get install libemail-address-perl
```

The general case:

```
apt-cache search Email::Address
```

Which gives you output like (but sometimes more than one package):

```
libemail-address-perl - RFC 2822 Address Parsing and Creation
```

Then, you can optionally use this to verify that the package is the right one:

```
apt-cache show libemail-address-perl
```

And finally the apt-get install that I started with.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much. I especially appreciate the steps involved. However, now my log shows; "Can't locate Email/MIME/Modifier.pm in @INC" so i guess i'll try your steps to get that package and so-on. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, when I run apt-cache search Email::MIME - I get: "E: Invalid operation seach"

Comment: try this: apt-get install libemail-mime-modifier-perl

Comment: "apt-get update" to update the package info might be necessary, too.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a newer version of Bugzilla, you might consider (re-)installing Perl 5.8 to a different directory. Don't overwrite the OS's.

In the past I have learned the hard way to keep the OS version and the App version of Perl in separate directories. Let the OS manage/fill it's Perl version requirements, and make sure you meet the requirements of the App in a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
  perl -MCPAN -e shell 
  install Email::Address
```

Maybe? I'm no perl person...

Comment: Thanks, I did that and then Email::MIME (which appeared in the logs next), now I get Email/MIME/Modifier.pm ... :)

Comment: That would be similar to the above, except Email::Address::Modifier - the way perl separates namespaces like that is :: instead of /

Answer (score 1):

You are using Perl 5.10 - are you trying to install an older version of Bugzilla which doesn't work with it?

Use a more recent Bugzilla ([3.0.2](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=390442) and up) or [see here](http://markmail.org/message/ee756b345n3gg7gh#query:%22subroutine%20reference%20at%20%2Fusr%2Fshare%2Fperl5%2FBugzilla%2FTemplate.pm%20line%2059.%22+page:1+mid:2qcj53beh7356gk6+state:results) for a workaround.

Comment: Ok cool, I might just bite the bullet and upgrade bugzilla.. its a really old version we have... I'll update when I am done. :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to run apt-get -f install, It may fix your broken packages.